# Connecting multiple arrows to one in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I just started working with EA and I am doing my first diagram. I want multiple boxes (documents in diagram) to point to 1 other box but I want it to look nice, that is I want there to be just one head of the arrow and the other arrows to connect to the arrow that's pointing to the box

So my question is - Is it possible to connect a couple of arrows to one (let's say I want the secondary arrows to meet in the middle of the main arrow)

Preview image of what I would like to achieve:
[image: Preview image of what I would like to achieve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UML and related languages do not allow connectors to connect to other connectors; connectors run between two elements (strictly speaking *one or* two, since a connector can connect an element to itself).

That said, any modelling tool allows you to move the connectors around in the diagram in order to superimpose them to achieve the visual effect you describe.

In EA, you can add bends to a connector using Ctrl-click. You can also change the line style of a connector by right-clicking it. Finally, in Tools - Options - Links you can select "tree" style as the default for Generalizations.

Comment: I did end up using the tree style where it fitted. Other than that I used junction, which graphically wasn't exactly what I hoped for but logically it worked out just fine.